# Me devuelve error al intentar ejecutar un comando de powershell con xp_cmdshell en sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo este código:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 
'powershell.exe -command "(Get-Process notepad|?{$_.SI -ne 0}).MainWindowTitle|%{($_ -     split '':'')[0]}"'
```

Básicamente me muestra los archivos que están abiertos por el bloc de notas. En el terminal va bien, pero en cuanto lo lanzo con este procedimiento almacenado me devuelve este error:

> Msg 15121, Level 16, State 21, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Error al ejecutar xp_cmdshell. Error al llamar a 'CreateProcess'; código de error: '5'.

Con comandos básicos de cmd funciona perfectamente. Por ejemplo si hago un "set", para que me muestre todas las variables de entorno, me devuelve el resultado correcto. Lo mismo con otros comandos de cmd, pero cuando lo intento con powershell no va.

He activado todas las variables de configuración necesarias, pero aún así soy incapaz de ejecutar ese pequeño script. He consultado por internet y seguido varios consejos, pero no he logrado nada. A ver si alguien de aquí me puede orientar.